# How to use the content provider for SQLite

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, locking

I created an `application` that creates and uses an `SQLitedatabase`, I can store data in the `database` and also `select, update, insert and delete` data from the `database`, I'am using `multiple threads` in my `application` that make use of the `database`. When they want to interact with the `database`, they always go this way: `Classname -> LogicDatabase -> database`.

**The problem:**

I sometimes get: `"Database is Locked(5)"` in my `output log`. It is not giving me any trouble using my `application` and everything just works alright, but I'am concerned about the warning. So I searched the internet(googled) and there where more people trying to prevent their `database` from `locking`.

The questions where most of the time mentioning a `Content Provider` to deal with the problem.

**My question:**

How do I use a `content provider` for dealing with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot use [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) in Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you implement something like an utility class to access your DB?

Comment: Aaaah, sorry. Then my question will be: how to prevent database from locking

Comment: I think its a multi threading issue. How are you using the db inside your code?